# Labeling a vertical asymptote written upwards (only using pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like the code that instructs TikZ to plot the asymptotes to the graph for the rational function `y=(x^{2})/(x^{2}-9)`. What is the code for plotting these lines as a dashed lines with arrowheads?  These should be a little shorter than the axes. 
The labels `x=-3` and `x=3` are to be typeset on the vertical asymptotes. Preferably, they would be typeset towards the bottom arrowheads, going upwards. (How do I label the axes? `y` is to be typeset to the right and above the top arrowhead on the y-axis, and `x` is to be typeset to the right and below the right arrowhead on the x-axis.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    ytick={-2},xtick={-2}
]
\addplot[samples=250,domain=-15:15] {(x^2)/(x^2-9)};
\draw[dashed,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}})
                       -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Screenshot please....

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It seems as if you did not make any attempt to change it at all. First try changing `(x+2)/(x-1)` to your desired function `((x)^2)/((x)^2)-9)` and change the domain as desired.  You can add `shorten <=1.0ex, , shorten >=1.0ex` option to to the `dashed` line to get them shorter than the axis.

Comment: @user60254: A lot of your recent questions consist of a long `PGFplots` example where you list lots of small things which you would like changed. I'd recommend taking a look at the PGFplots manual and really trying to *understand* the code instead of having others modify it for you.

Comment: I have spent hours looking at this manual. It takes several minutes to Look for each instance of a word. Can you tell me the page that describes the option `shorten<=1ex, shorten>=1ex` and the page I can find to label the vertical asymptotes x=-3 and x=3 oging upwards?

Comment: If you just want to look up words, there is an index at the very end of the manual. For the rest of your questions, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For labeling the axes, look at the section about axis labels (section 4.9.3 in my version). You probably want something like `xlabel=$x$` and `ylabel=$y$` in your `axis` options.

For labeling the asymptotes, you can place a `node[left] {-3}` after the coordinates in the `\draw[dashed]` command:

```
\draw[dashed,latex-latex] ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,1}})
                       -- ({{1,0}}|-{{axis description cs:1,0}})
                          node[left] {-3};
```

Finally, `shorten >` and `shorten <` are TikZ options, which shorten the end and the start of a line, respectively, by the specified length. Simply add them to the options of the `\draw` command.

Comment: I used the commands `xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$` in the options for the axis. The "x" is placed above the right arrowhead and the "y" is placed to the right of the top arrowhead - and on top of both the graph and the vertical line x=1. I used the command `/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};` after the axis options, as described on pages 200 and 201 - in 4.9 of the manual.  Nothing happened. I would like to place the "x" below and to the right of the right arrowhead on the x-axis, and I would like to place the "y" above and to the right of the right arrowhead on the y-axis.

Comment: @user143462: Sorry for not replying. I didn't get a notification because you forgot to add @Fritz at the beginning of your comment. I don't know why the `ylabel shift` doesn't work -- maybe it has to to with `axis lines=middle`. But actually, this comment would make an *excellent* question! Just add a small MWE containing *only* an empty axis and the labels, and you're good to go.

Comment: I was told that making a comment to a user's post would prompt tex.stackexchange to inform that user that I had made a comment.  I guess that I will be in the habit of adding "@user" to my post.  I just replied to Harish Kumar about my question.  (I didn't enter "@Harish Kumar" to my comment.  I guess that I should make another comment to inform him of my previous comment.  It sounds ridiculous.  Doesn't it?)  Please take a look at it.  I am trying to make a few graphs for a file that I need to send to my Calculus class. Only properly displaying these graphs is delaying me.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed sound ridiculous -- I don't quite understand the rules myself. Specifically I should get a notification for all comments on my answers according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/. For positioning you should look at this answer, which demonstrates the necessary technique: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122766/12440. You just have to change the `anchor` and set the `at` to `1.00` instead of `1.05`.