# Labeling a slant asymptote

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using TikZ and pgfplots for the first time. (I am using it so that I can send class notes to students in a Calculus class that I am teaching.) I have a graph with a slant asymptote. Before I can use pgfplots for the graph, I have some adjustments needed for just the lines in the graph!

I saw in another post that `shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex` would shorten a line at each end by 2ex. This command shortened the vertical line but not the slanted line.   I want arrowheads on both lines; they are on the vertical line but not the slanted line.  I want the lines labeled in the same direction as the lines ... but off the line. So, I need to move one label up and one label to the right.  Since arctan(3/2) = 56.31 degrees, I used `rotate=56.31` in the options for the node. Is there a "slant" command for drawing such labels in the same direction as the line?  One more thing. The label "y" for the y-axis is too close to the vertical line x=3/2. How do I adjust its position? (I don't like the position of the "x" for the x-axis, too.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
]

\draw[dashed,latex-latex,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex] (-13,-17) -- (13,22) node[right,rotate=56.31,pos=0.1]{$\scriptstyle{y=(3/2)x+5/2}$};
\draw[dashed,latex-latex,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex] ({1.5,0} |- {{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1.5,0}} |- {{axis description cs:1,-1}}) node[right,rotate=90,pos=0.5]{$\scriptstyle{x=3/2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: For positioning the x and y labels, see [How can I adjust the position of xlabel and ylabel with pgfplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122747/how-can-i-adjust-the-position-of-xlabel-and-ylabel-with-pgfplots)

Answer (score 10):

The reason why the `shorten` commands don't seem to work reliably is because you can't see the ends of your lines: they're outside the plot area, and are clipped off. To see the full lines, add `clip=false` to your `axis` options.

I would approach this differently: instead of using `\draw` commands, you can use "real" plots with the `\addplot` command. That way, you can specify the equations directly, instead of having to calculate the angle for the rotation beforehand.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    domain=-15:15, samples=50,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
]

\addplot [dashed, latex-latex] {(3/2)*x+5/2} node [pos=0.25, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$y=(3/2)x+5/2$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex] (1.5,x) node [pos=0.25, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=3/2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice!  I had not seen the command `\addplot (1.5,x)` for drawing vertical lines.  Is that in the manual?  Yes, I like the `sloped` option for the `\addplot` command.  I think the only modifications that I need are the positions to the "x" and "y" on the axes.

Comment: @Adelyn: `\addplot (<x>, <y>)` is the syntax for drawing parametric plots. See section 4.3.3
"Computing Coordinates with Mathematical Expressions" of the current manual for more info (it can be a bit overwhelming at first...)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sloped` option instead of computing the angle:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also replaced the slat fractions with a `\frac` as I think that looks much better.
- To get the axis labels at the tips you can use the `Axis Labels At Tip` style that I extracted from [How to properly scale a TikZ/PGF picture which has a `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/how-to-properly-scale-a-tikz-pgf-picture-which-has-a-beginaxis-endaxis).
- The reason why there were not arrowheads on both ends can be seen if you set `clip=false`. The lines were way beyond the displayed range. So you can either edit the coordinates to get the end points of the lines into range or just increase the amount you shorten the line with. In the MWE below I increased the `shorten` amounts as that was simpler than computing appropriate coordinates to maintain the same slope and position.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/how-to-properly-scale-a-tikz-pgf-picture-which-has-a-beginaxis-endaxis
%%
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Labels At Tip/.style={
        xlabel style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)}, 
            xshift=1.5ex, anchor=center
        },
        ylabel style={
            at={(current axis.above origin)}, 
            yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-12:12,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
%    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    Axis Labels At Tip,
    %clip=false
]

\draw[dashed,latex-latex,shorten <=4ex, shorten >=15ex] (axis cs: -13,-17) -- (axis cs: 13,22) node[right,sloped, above,pos=0.15]{$y=\frac{3}{2}x+ \frac{5}{2} $};
\draw[dashed,latex-latex,shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex] ({1.5,0} |- {{axis description cs:1,1}}) -- ({{1.5,0}} |- {{axis description cs:1,0}}) node[right,rotate=90, below, pos=0.65]{$x= \frac{3}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response.  You were the first one to reply to me on this site!  I have two comments on your code.  Why don't your lines have arrowheads? The only differences between your code and Jake's code is he uses `clip=false` and `\addplot`. I also want to move the labels "x" and "y" on the axes. I looked at another posting. This is the code:  `xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$, every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west,}, every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south,}` How do I get "x" below and to the right of right arrowhead?

Comment: How do I get "y" above and to the right (or to the left) of the top arrowhead?

Comment: @Adelyn: Both your comments should now be addressed in the revised solution.

Comment: @ Peter Grill  Thanks!  I did not have time to find this in the manual.  I will look in the manual for the description of the `Axis Labels At Tip` command later. The axes for all the graphs in this particular LaTeX file should look the same. So, it is convenient to have this code.

Comment: @Adelyn: As mentioned in the answer, `Axis Labels At Tip` is from [How to properly scale a TikZ/PGF picture which has a `\begin{axis}…\end{axis}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/how-to-properly-scale-a-tikz-pgf-picture-which-has-a-beginaxis-endaxis).  It is _not_ a style that is in the documentation.  But `xlabel style` and `ylabel style` should be in the documentation.

Comment: @ Peter Grill  This command also places "x" in the appropriate position with respect to the right arrowhead of the x-axis: `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}`.  Is there one code which is preferred?

Comment: @Adelyn: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. I think you should post a separate question as your question seems to be about labeling the axis as opposed to a slant asymptote.  We like to keep questions focused on one topic so that they are more easily searchable and thus more likely to be of help to a larger audience.