# Scaling of x-axis and y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made following codes. Please refer this, it is very easy to compile.
Now my question is,

i want scaling of x-axis like `{-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,....55}` it is already in mwe.

but i want to lable y-axis as `{-3, 0, 3, 6, 9, ......24}`

Please guide me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (-2,0) -- (12,0)node[right]{$x$};
        \draw[thick,latex-latex] (0,-2) -- (0,12)node[above]{$y$};
        \node at (-0.3,-0.3) {O};
        \foreach \x/\l in {-1/-5,1/5,2/10,3/15,4/20,5/25,6/30,7/35,8/40,9/45,10/50,11/55,11/60}{
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$\l$] at (\x,0) {};
            \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=left:$\l$] at (0,\x) {};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You should take a look at the `axis` environment of `pgfplots` (see http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net ) which also provides scaling and a nicer way to define axis.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something with `pgfplots` which offers a little convenience for producting such axis, e.g. you can just rescale everything by changing `width`and `height`.
You have to specify both the range `xmin=`,`xmax=`, which would also procude ticks automatically (less then yours in number) and your own `xticks={}` which can be given similar to `TikZ`. Then you do the same for `y`. The next two lines place the axis at `0`. And taking the axis label placement from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122747/how-can-i-adjust-the-position-of-xlabel-and-ylabel-with-pgfplots) we get

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt} % This is the default columnsep for all pages
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,height=12cm,
        xmin=-10,xmax=55,
        xtick = {-10,-5,...,50},
        ymin=-3,ymax=24,
        ytick = {-3,0,...,24},
        axis y line=middle,
        axis x line=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.025)},
            anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.025)},
            anchor=south,
        },
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]

and you can just add plots inside the `axis` whithout having to think about the rescaling you used in your example.

Comment: A big thank, asking a small question if i want to put dot instead of tick on axis at every point for this what should i do?

Comment: one more question how can i get back same desire out put by making changes in my MWE.(given in question)

Comment: I just added something to your code, just copy the code from my answer. You basically need the `pgfplots` package I added in the preamble. About the circles - I have to look, what can be done there.

Comment: I can't find anything on that, maybe it's a good idea to post that as a seperate question here: How to change the ticks of a pgfplot to circles.